# NetBeans error al instalar java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

Tags: java, netbeans, windows

Esto pasa después de aceptar los términos y condiciones y darle en Next (Tengo Windows 11)
y si tengo instalado JDK 20 y 17 ya hice instalación de nuevo de todo nada no encuentro solución

when I try to install netbeans, a critical error appears saying:

> An unexpected exception happened in thread AWT-EventQueue-0
>
> Exceptions:
>
> ```
>  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>  Comparison method violates its general contract!"
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]